# HQL query with left join fetch on collection

Tags: hql

I have a problem with a `hql` query, I use the last version on hibernate on `jboss7`.

So, I have `table1` linked to `table2` and `table2` has an attribute (SET) references to `table3`.

Here is a small schema

```
TABLE1-----TABLE2(attribute: transfer manyToMany)        TABLE3(attribute elements)
```

here is my query:

```
select t1 from TABLE1 t1
left join fetch t1.TABLE2 t2
left join fetch t2.transfers tf (here we have a list of T3)
```

How to load the elements in T3 with a left join fetch, if it's possible at all?

I try `tf.elements` but I receive `indexOutOfBounds` exception.

I tried to add the T3 in the select statement and to add a condition but I didn't find a condition on the list `tf`.

Thanks

Comment: please specify a version, since "the last version" can be a different one to your version from now on

Comment: Solved now, relation in eager solve the problem